# Get the first and last occurrence index for every event

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas.Dataframe where in one column, the values equal to 1 are related to a repetitive event.

How it is possible to get the first and last occurrence index for every event?

For instance, looking on the example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]})
```

The result should be:

```py
idxs = [[2,4], [9,12], [17,18]]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can add a column `b` with a different number for every group of consecutive number

```py
df["b"] = (df["a"]!=df["a"].shift()).cumsum()
```

```bash
    a  b
0   0  1
1   0  1
2   1  2
3   1  2
4   1  2
5   0  3
6   0  3
7   0  3
8   0  3
9   1  4
10  1  4
11  1  4
12  1  4
13  0  5
14  0  5
15  0  5
16  0  5
17  1  6
18  1  6
19  0  7
```

Then we consider only strikes of ones and for each group we take the first and the last index

```py
df[df["a"].eq(1)].groupby("b")\
    .apply(lambda x: [x.index.min(), x.index.max()])
```

```bash
b
2      [2, 4]
4     [9, 12]
6    [17, 18]
```

if you are looking for a list as output you can just add `.to_list()`

```py
df[df["a"].eq(1)].groupby("b")\
    .apply(lambda x: [x.index.min(), x.index.max()])\
    .to_list()
```

```bash
[[2, 4], [9, 12], [17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy` to solve this problem,use `values`,`where`,`concatenate`,`diff` method.

```py
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]})
arr = df.values.flatten()
start_indexes = np.where(np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(arr) == 1)))[0]
end_indexes = np.where(np.concatenate((np.diff(arr) == -1, [0])))[0]
print(list(zip(starts, ends))
```

Comment: I realized after posting my answer, that I used a logic similar to yours. I think it's a good way to go, more efficient than using `groupby`! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create grouper to divide group

```
grouper = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
```

`grouper.head()`:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
```

The first two 0's belong to group 1, the next three consecutive 1's belong to group 2

then groupby by grouper

```
g = df.groupby(grouper)['a']
(df[df['a'].eq(1)]
 .groupby(grouper)['a'].agg([pd.Series.first_valid_index, pd.Series.last_valid_index])
 .values.tolist())
```

output:

```
[[2, 4], [9, 12], [17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using boolean masks and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to reshape:

```
# value is a 1
m = df['a'].eq(1)
# value is either preceded or followed by a non-1
m2 = ~(m.shift(fill_value=False)|m.shift(-1, fill_value=False))

# keep those indices, reshape 2 by 2, convert to list
out = df.index[m&m2].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 2)).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4], [9, 12], [17, 18]]
```